# Change reCAPTCHA response to alert() instead of loading new page

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm using reCAPTCHA and I'd like to show the response if the CATPCHA was filled in incorrectly as an `alert();` rather than it loading a new page. How can I do that?

This is the form action:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="verify.php">
```

With this in the verify.php file:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "(my key)";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your method on form submit like--

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="verify.php" onsubmit="mymethod()" >
```

OR use jquery, something like that --

```
<script>

    $("form").submit(function() {
      if ($("input:first").val() == "correct") {
        $("span").text("Validated...").show();
        return true;
      }
      $("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But how would I display that as an alert?

Comment: using ajax u can call your verification file in the method and fetch response in to it ..if it returns true- return true otherwise return false...hope it makes sense to you :)

Comment: Sorry I don't know ajax. Isn't there a simple way to just show the error message as a alert box using php?

Comment: @Teamworksdesign.com i dont think so php allow alert boxes on itself;) u have to use jquery/javascript for that :)

Comment: @Rob - not really, because the form submit has already started the load of a "separate" page.  By the time verify.php has checked the reCaptcha correctness, it is too late to "simply show an alert" on the original page.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the Javascript for the alert on the new page.

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {

  // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
  echo("<script>alert('The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.');</script">);
  die();

} else {
  // Your code here to handle a successful verification
}
```

Comment: @Rob - if you want that to be an alert, instead of a die, then uses php to write out the javascript to invoke the alert.  Something like: **echo "<script> alert('reCAPTCHA failure! Try again!');</script>";**  But it still happens at the top of the "verify.php" output page, not in the original page.

Comment: Since he explicitely stated that he does NOT want to load a new page this answer is pretty useless.